# Could there be Sylow-2 subgroups of $S_4$ with order 2 and 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

We have the symmetric group $S_4$ whose order is $24=2^3\times3$. By the first Sylow theorem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group. If $p$ is a prime and $p^k$ divides |G|, then G has a subgroup of order $p^k$.

Is that right if I say $G$ has subgroups of order $2^1=2, 2^2=4,2^3=8,3^1=3$? If so , how can I find the Sylow-2 group(s) with orders 2 and 4? Thanks:)

Comment: A group of order $2$ is generated by an element of order $2$

Comment: Note the Sylow theorem doesn't say there is only one subgroup of the given order. [I mention that since you ask how to find "the" subgroup of those orders.]

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks!!

Comment: Your terminology is wrong. The subgroups of order $2$ and $4$ are not Sylow $2$-subgroups. Those are the subgroups of order $8$.

Comment: The subgroups of order $p^a$ are just called "$p$-subgroups." The only time they are called **Sylow** $p$-subgroups (or "$p$-Sylow subtroups") is when the $a$ is largest possible; in this case, $p=2$, $a=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first calculate the order of each element .
While constructing a subgroup of  order 2 you need to include one identity element and one another element of order 2, since S4 has 9 elements of order 2 we can construct 9 subgroups of order 2.
While constructing a subgroup of order 3 ,we need to include one identity element and one element of order 3 .Since  S4 has 8 elements of order 3, you can construct 8 subgroups order 3. Similarly you can construct all remaining subgroups .
However existence of these subgroups (Sylow first therom) explained by you is correct .

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why does S4 have 9 elements of order 2?

Comment: In order to calculate the number of elements of order 2 you have following two methods :1) write all 24 elements of S4 and find a.a for all a in S4 , if it becomes the identity then it is an element of order 2 ,otherwise skip it . In the second method at first consider all the partition of 4 : 1) 1+1+1+1 . 2) 1+1+2 . 3) 1+3 . 4) 4  . 5) 2+2 . Now pick out the partitions whose l.c.m. is 2 , these are {1,1,2} and {2,2} . Now calculate size of conjugacy class corresponding to each partition . For {1,1,2} it is 6 and for {2,2} it is 3 . Hence number of elements of order 2 are 9.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $S_4$ has $8$ elements of order $3$, but only $4$ distinct subgroups of order $3$